# Xcode - Displaying variations of using Firebase and Algolia

Tags: xcode, firebase, algolia

I've got data in my Algolia index and Firebase Database that are stored as presented in the first image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjs5I.png)

There is a parent exercise (in this case "Chest Press") which has two variation factors ("type" and "variation"). When a user searches for an exercise, I would like the data to be presented as shown in the second image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFeFy.png)

Is this possible using my current database structure? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would flatten this out in your index so that each exercise/variation is a unique record. This will aid Algolia indexing and speed up search.